# Invalid Win32 program with C runtime libs 2011 on WinXP

Tags: c++, windows-8

I have compilled program in Visual Studio 2011 on Windows consumer preview with v110 toolkit (c runtime 2011) and it refuse to run on Windows XP even with needed runtime dlls for 2011 libs (from VC/redist/) folder. It says that file is not valid Win32 app. How I can get that app to run on XP?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't building the application in 64bits and trying to run it in 32bits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The VS 11 Beta does not support Windows XP as a target platform (or as a development platform, just to be complete).

There have been some statements from Microsoft personnel that this might change for RTM.

But I wouldn't hold my breath.

If you're adventurous, here's an article that describes in detail how you can create your own library that will smooth over the things that prevent the runtime library from allowing an application to load on WinXP:

- [How to get Visual C++ 2012 (VC 11 Beta) statically linked CRT and MFC applications to run on Windows XP](http://tedwvc.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/how-to-get-visual-c-2012-vc-11-beta-statically-linked-crt-and-mfc-applications-to-run-on-windows-xp/)

**Update (15 June 2012):**

Microsoft has reconsidered not allowing VC++ 2012 to target Window XP.  Unfortunately the decision came too late to allow targeting WinXP to be supported in RTM, so you'll have to wait for a subsequent update:

- [Targeting Windows XP with C++ in Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/06/15/10320645.aspx)

Comment: Sadly Michael is right. XP is not supported in the VC11 Preview, and as there is no comment about from ms, it most probably wont be in rtm version too

Comment: Updated the post to reflect a recent change Microsoft has announced regarding targeting WinXP.

Answer (score 1):

Applications compiled with Visual Studio 11 *do not* run on XP. Please vote for [this request](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2287078-allow-mfc-11-to-run-in-xp-sp3) -- perhaps Microsoft will realize their mistake then.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 32-bit cross-compiler, or rebuild the app on Windows XP for 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are changes to the PE version as well as the CRT for Visual Studio 2011 which means, even with binary modification (yuk) XP is not supported. To quote the [answer from Microsoft](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressinstall/thread/5e0134fe-664b-41b8-806d-b2a4ab226134):

> Visual Studio 11 Beta doesn't support Windows XP. As to Visual Studio
>   11 final release, there's no such information published yet. We will
>   refer to the official website for supported OS.

Comment: As for the final Visual C++ 2012 RTM there is no XP support either.  Official reference at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/05/18/a-look-ahead-at-the-visual-studio-11-product-lineup-and-platform-support.aspx